# VBA - Change sheet reference in cell formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a code where I change all references to a specific sheet in a selected range to a new chosen sheet - i.e. the same relative cell reference in a different sheet. The sheet reference to be replaced (Original Sheet) and the replacement sheet reference (New Sheet) are chosen by the user via comboboxes in a userform. The code works fine as long as both the sheet names are comparable with regards to whether they need single quotation marks, i.e. if OSheet = "Sheet1" and NSheet = "Sheet2" or OSheet = "Sheet - 1" and NSheet = "Sheet - 2". However, I run into problems when they have different requirements for single quotation marks, e.g. OSheet = "Sheet1" and NSheet = "Sheet - 2", as the sheet reference in the formula would be Sheet1! vs 'Sheet - 2!'.

Do any of you have any tips on how I can fix this problem and standardize this code?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.OriginalSheet.Clear
Me.NewSheet.Clear

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    With Me.OriginalSheet
        .AddItem Sheets(i).Name
    End With
    With Me.NewSheet
        .AddItem Sheets(i).Name
    End With
Next i

With Me.OriginalSheet
    .ListIndex = 0
End With

With Me.NewSheet
    .ListIndex = 0
End With

End Sub  

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OriginalSheet, NewSheet As String
Dim xRange As Range
Set xRange = Selection

OSheet = Me.OriginalSheet.Value
NSheet = Me.NewSheet.Value

    With xRange
        .Replace What:=OSheet, Replacement:=NSheet, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                 SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim OriginalSheet` in `CommandButton1_Click` is not set. What exactly is the idea there?

Comment: Can you not just check the sheet names and add single quotes to it before you use the variables?

Comment: @Zac Yes, that is my current working hypothesis. But I'm not sure how  I would do this in an efficient way.

Comment: Once you set the values in `OSheet` and `NSheet` variables, check if there are spaces in the string (you can do this with `InStr`.. `If InStr(1, OSheet, " ") > 0 Then`). If there are put quotes round your string .. i.e. **`OSheet = "'" & OSheet & "'"`**

Comment: @Zac Thank you. That is very helpful. I guess I will have to check for other characters that would lead to single quotation marks around the sheet name as well, e.g. ) and #. Any suggestions on this? Not even sure which characters will have to be searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:
To test for more than one possible character, you can use [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matching. The code below uses late binding to create a Regular Expression object, and assigns a pattern that matches if the tested string contains any characters that are not letters, numbers, underscore or period, or starts with a number:

```
Dim objRegExp As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]|^\d"
```

You can then use the RegExp.Test function as the Expression parameter of the [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/iif-function) function like so:

```
Osheet = IIf(objRegExp.Test(Me.OriginalSheet.Value), "'" & Me.OriginalSheet.Value & "'", Me.OriginalSheet.Value)
NSheet = IIf(objRegExp.Test(Me.NewSheet.Value), "'" & Me.NewSheet.Value & "'", Me.NewSheet.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Including the above will definitely improve the code and make it work in most cases. However, to make it "universal", I will also have to check for other characters that would lead to a requirement for single quotation marks when referencing the sheet, e.g. characters like ( , #. I'm not sure how I can include an exhaustive list / create the code to handle this problem efficiently, so any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: @PVD I have updated my answer to a method that will identify what I think are all the criteria that require references to be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly. I was able to find an alternative solution by looping through characters in the sheet name using Chr(), but your code looks more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a decent solution after some thinking, but forgot to post it. That being said, beldin0's answer works like a charm. Posting my alternative solution for anyone interested.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OSheet As String, NSheet As String
Dim xRange As Range
Set xRange = Selection

n = 0
k = 0

For i = 32 To 126
    Select Case i
    Case 46, 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 95, 97 To 122
        'Do nothing
    Case Else
        If InStr(1, Me.OriginalSheet.Value, Chr(i)) <> 0 Then n = n + 1

        If InStr(1, Me.NewSheet.Value, Chr(i)) <> 0 Then k = k + 1

    End Select
Next i

If IsNumeric(Left(Me.OriginalSheet.Value, 1)) Then n = n + 1
If IsNumeric(Left(Me.NewSheet.Value, 1)) Then k = k + 1

If n > 0 Then OSheet = "'" & Me.OriginalSheet.Value & "'" & "!" Else OSheet = Me.OriginalSheet.Value & "!"
If k > 0 Then NSheet = "'" & Me.NewSheet.Value & "'" & "!" Else NSheet = Me.NewSheet.Value & "!"

    With xRange
        .Replace What:=OSheet, Replacement:=NSheet, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                 SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With

Unload Me

Set xRange = Nothing

End Sub
```